# Show the tooltip make button function won't run c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i already could show the tooltip on each button whenever the mouse button hover that button. However, the button function did not run, but the tooltip shown.

Here is the code:

```
    public static float textHeight = 25;
    public static float textWidth = 1350;
    public static float buttonHeight = 25;
    public static float buttonWidth = 100;
    public static float screenTextHeight = 745;

public virtual void TurnOnGUI()
    {
        Rect buttonRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 3, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect tooltipRect = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 3 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect textRect = new Rect(10, Screen.height - screenTextHeight, textWidth, textHeight);
        Rect _buttonRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect _buttonRect_ = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 1, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect _tooltipRect = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 2 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect _tooltipRect_ = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 1 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        label1.normal.textColor = Color.red;

        //Text Field
        if (GUI.Button(textRect, ""))
        {

        }

        //ToolTip Text
        //GUI.Button(buttonRect, new GUIContent("Move", "Move the Player"));
        //GUI.Label(tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);

        GUI.tooltip = null;
        //Move Button
        if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Move"))
        {
            if (!moving)
            {
                GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
                moving = true;
                attacking = false;
                GameManager.instance.HighlightTilesAt(gridPosition, Color.blue, movementPerActionPoint);
            }

            else
            {
                moving = false;
                attacking = false;
                GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
            }
        }

        //ToolTip Text
        //GUI.Button(_buttonRect, new GUIContent("Attack", "Attack the Player"));
        //GUI.Label(_tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);

        GUI.tooltip = null;
        //Attack Button
        if (GUI.Button(_buttonRect, "Attack"))
        {
            if (!attacking)
            {
                GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
                moving = false;
                attacking = true;
                GameManager.instance.HighlightTilesAt(gridPosition, Color.red, attackRange);
            }

            else
            {
                moving = false;
                attacking = false;
                GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
            }
        }

        //ToolTip Text
        //GUI.Button(_buttonRect_, new GUIContent("End Turn", "End Turn the Player"));
        //GUI.Label(_tooltipRect_, GUI.tooltip, label1);

        GUI.tooltip = null;
        //End Turn Button
        if (GUI.Button(_buttonRect_, "End Turn"))
        {
            GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
            actionPoints = 2;
            moving = false;
            attacking = false;
            GameManager.instance.NextTurn();
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot (The mouse hover at the "Move" button and make red color tooltip), tooltip shown but when i click the "Move" button, it won't run (won't show the blue grid for movement):

[image]

But when i delete the tooltip text, the "Move" button function run perfectly:

[image]

How can i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Demo : MonoBehaviour {
    bool clicked = false;

    void OnGUI() {
        clicked = GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), new GUIContent("Click me", "This is the tooltip"));
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 40, 100, 40), GUI.tooltip);
        if(clicked)
        {
        //do your stuff after click 
           print(clicked);
        }
    }
}
```

i.e

```
public static float textHeight = 25;
public static float textWidth = 1350;
public static float buttonHeight = 25;
public static float buttonWidth = 100;
public static float screenTextHeight = 745;

bool move=false,attack=false,endTurn=false;  //Added

public virtual void TurnOnGUI()
{
    Rect buttonRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 3, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    Rect tooltipRect = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 3 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    Rect textRect = new Rect(10, Screen.height - screenTextHeight, textWidth, textHeight);
    Rect _buttonRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    Rect _buttonRect_ = new Rect(0, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 1, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    Rect _tooltipRect = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 2 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    Rect _tooltipRect_ = new Rect(100 + 10, Screen.height - buttonHeight * 1 + 5, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    label1.normal.textColor = Color.red;

    //Text Field
    if (GUI.Button(textRect, ""))
    {

    }

    //ToolTip Text
    move = GUI.Button(buttonRect, new GUIContent("Move", "Move the Player"));
    GUI.Label(tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);

    GUI.tooltip = null;
    //Move Button
    if (move)   //edited
    {
        if (!moving)
        {
            GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
            moving = true;
            attacking = false;
            GameManager.instance.HighlightTilesAt(gridPosition, Color.blue, movementPerActionPoint);
        }

        else
        {
            moving = false;
            attacking = false;
            GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
        }
    }

    //ToolTip Text
    attack = GUI.Button(_buttonRect, new GUIContent("Attack", "Attack the Player"));
    GUI.Label(_tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);

    GUI.tooltip = null;
    //Attack Button
    if (attack)   //edited
    {
        if (!attacking)
        {
            GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
            moving = false;
            attacking = true;
            GameManager.instance.HighlightTilesAt(gridPosition, Color.red, attackRange);
        }

        else
        {
            moving = false;
            attacking = false;
            GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
        }
    }

    //ToolTip Text
    endTurn = GUI.Button(_buttonRect_, new GUIContent("End Turn", "End Turn the Player"));
    GUI.Label(_tooltipRect_, GUI.tooltip, label1);

    GUI.tooltip = null;
    //End Turn Button
    if (endTurn)   //edited
    {
        GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
        actionPoints = 2;
        moving = false;
        attacking = false;
        GameManager.instance.NextTurn();
    }
}
```